# Symfony adding Roles column to the admin dashboard

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony. I created an admin dashboard using the easyadmin bundle.
However, only the email, username, ID are appearing on list of users page. I want to add a column role for roles as well.
Should I modify this function ? and if so how ? what is the word that I can use to express that roles is an array not a textfield.

```
  public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IntegerField::new('id', 'ID')->onlyOnIndex(),
            TextField::new('username'),
            TextField::new('email'),
           //here !! x AssociationField::new('roles'),
        ];
    }
```

I tried

```
CollectionField::new('roles'),
```

but it returned the number of roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ChoiceField::new('roles')->setChoices(['ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'])->allowMultipleChoices()
```

should work.

Comment: hello i tried this `ArrayField::new('roles'),` and it worked ! thank you anws :)